# SASS Pseudo hover class not working (disappears almost instantly)

Tags: class, hyperlink, sass, hover, state

My objective is to create a simple hover state where a orange line appears underneath the nav link.

With the code below when I hover I get nothing, but as I move cursor away from the link, the line appears for a millisecond and then disappears.

There is no errors from compass, the hover state works momentarily but then vanishes! I've come back to this several times but failed. Professionals please shed light on this, please...

Code:

```
nav {
    @include make-row();
    @include make-sm-column(12);

    .main-nav {
        float: right;
        list-style: none;

        li {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-left: 40px;
            margin-top: 55px;

            a {
                &:link,
                &:visited {
                    padding: 8px 0;
                    color: #fff;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    text-transform: uppercase;
                    font-size: 0.9em;
                    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
                    transition: border-bottom 0.8s;
                }
                &:hover,
                &:active {
                    border-bottom: 2px $seconday-color;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Over and out.

Comment: Unless you have a Sass->CSS compilation issue, only post the compiled CSS.  This is not a Sass problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `transition: border-bottom` use `transition: border-color`, then in `&:hoover` state all you need is `border-color: $seconday-color;`.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oxunwt4g/